# Histogram in GNUplot, each bar with a different color

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I am trying to make a barplot with GNUplot, were each bar has a different color. I have found out in the manual that it can be done using *lc rgbcolor variable*.

My data folder looks like this,

```
ACB 0.106372
ASW 0.10909
BEB 0.110973
CDX 0.106577
CEU 0.102091
CHB 0.108829
CHS 0.110807
CLM 0.108803
```

My plot script is as follows,

```
set style histogram gap 2
set autoscale y

set style fill solid

set xtics rotate by 90 offset 0,-1.2


rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(r*10) + 256 * int(g*10) + int(b*10)
set boxwidth .5

set output "Plot.eps" 
plot "plot.tsv" using 2:xticlabels(1):(rgb($2,$2,$2)) with boxes lc rgb variable
```

I have used the rgb function that is shown in the GNUplot manual. But it shows the following error.

```
plot "plot.tsv" using 2:xticlabels(1):(rgb($2,$2,$2)) with boxes lc rgb variable
                                                                                ^
         "#Plot.plt", line 18: x range is invalid
```

I can't figure out what the error means.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually plotting with style "boxes", not "histograms".  That probably is what you want, but whereas for histograms the x coordinate is implicit, for boxes you have to provide an x coordinate in the first column even if you're OK with the ordinal numbers 0,1,2,3,...

So 
plot "plot.tsv" using 0:2:xticlabels(1):(rgb($2,$2,$2)) with boxes lc rgb variable

Oh, and you probably want to set the fillstyle also so that the colors are visible:
set style fill solid